# How to dislplay Data in Gridview if we have 2 Queries

Tags: asp.net

i have two Queries and for that two Queries i had taken **two Grid Views**

```
select course_name , start_date, end_date, timings, fee, branch_code from coursesprovided    where start_date>=Getdate() and branch_code='Ameerpet'

select course_name , start_date, end_date, timings, fee, branch_code from coursesprovided where start_date>=Getdate() and branch_code='Hi-Tech City'
```

**During my page load i need to display the Data in Grid View.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=gateway; User   Id=sa; Password=wilshire@rnd; Integrated Security=false";


            //Assigning Query
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "select course_name , start_date, end_date, timings, fee, branch_code from coursesprovided where start_date>=Getdate() and branch_code='Ameerpet'";

cmd.CommandText = "select course_name , start_date, end_date, timings, fee, branch_code  from coursesprovided where start_date>=Getdate() and branch_code='Ameerpet'";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            //Execute the COmmand
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            gvap.DataSource = ds;
            gvap.DataBind();
}
```

is There any alternative rather than taking **2 SQLcommands, 2 SqlDataAdapter, 2 Dataset**.....

Comment: I would rather suggest you to use server side table where you can show data from any source as much as you can without complexity. Google for asp.net table

Comment: Your `CommandText` is the same. Apart from that, yes, you could use the same but that would be less readable and more error-prone. It doesn't hurt to use different commands and adapters.

Comment: Since you have the same columns and data types, you could also use a UNION statement? That way, you wouldn't have to create a new table or view and you also wouldn't need two data adapters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just combine those two queries into one?

```
 SELECT [course_name], [start_date], [end_date], [timings], [fee], [branch_code] FROM [coursesprovided] WHERE [start_date] > = GETDATE() AND ([branch_code] ='Ameerpet' OR [branch_code] = 'Hi-Tech City')
```

Keep in mind that you should avoid hard-coding field values like that if at all possible, and use parameters instead.

```
 String branchCode1 = "Ameerpet";
 String branchCode2 = "H-Tech City";

 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [course_name], [start_date], [end_date], [timings], [fee], [branch_code] FROM [coursesprovided] WHERE [start_date] > = GETDATE() AND ([branch_code] = @BranchCode1 OR [branch_code] = @BranchCode2)";

 da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("BranchCode1", branchCode1);
 da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("BranchCode2", branchCode2);
```

That block of code is simplified...you could pass in the parameter values in any way that you wanted, and you should probably keep things clean by defining the entire thing as a separate function or stored procedure, so you could pass in whatever value you wanted. I just defined the two parameters in the code for illustration purposes.